# requestAnimationFrame messes up local variable sending from another function to render on canvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

My application has very long running lifespan. So I want to garbage collect unused functions on the fly by declare variables locally.

```
function Video1() {
    var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
    video1.play();
    drawCanvas(video1);
}

function drawCanvas(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;
    console.log(elem);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this.elem, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
};

var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
button1.addEventListener('click', Video1, false);
```

Putting the requestAnimationFrame in adding something like ***1373086307101.346*** as the **elem** value

I solve this with the setInterval method, but is there better way to do so as I mainly target mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `drawCanvas` expects an argument `elem`. When not provided - it is set to `undefined`.
By calling `requestAnimatinoFrame(drawCanvas)` you will call `drawCanvas` without any arugments. What you probably need is the wrapper function:

```
function wrapperForDrawCanvas() {
    // Obtain proper elem here

    drawCanvas(elem);
}
```

And then call `requestAnimationFrame(wrapperForDrawCanvas)` instead of `requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas)`. That way your `drawCanvas` will always get `elem` argument.

Comment: I tried but can't figure out how to obtain proper elem which you suggest above

Comment: What do you need this `elem` to be?